# How to Show 2 or more messagebox/messagedialog in UI

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am working on a windows 8.1 and phone 8 universal application.I have to show a session time out message using `messagebox/messagedialog` in phone and store.

But if any other `messagebox/messagedialog` present in the UI, i want to remove that one and show session timeout messagebox/messagedialog in that UI.

Is there is anyway to remove a `messagebox/messagedialog` after i show in the UI ?

Comment: Here's a logic since I dont have visual studio installed currently, just try to figure it out 

Where ever your app time out is happening (whichever class) add a delegate to it , and while opening a message dialog just add the event(say event A) to that delegate , in the event A  hide the message box using dispatcher and also after hiding you can display the new message box making use of the previous one and changing the content, whatever suits ur requirement.